# How to set custom "margin" on CSS

Tags: html, css

I have setted the `body`'s `margin` to 0 on `CSS`. But I couldn't setted the `div`'s margin. 
 So, I want to set another things' `margin` to 0; but the `abc` classed `div`'s `margin` to 5.
My code is:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  margin: 5;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: margin: 5px not just 5

Comment: @EvikGhazarian Or any valid unit. Px are most common though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly, you want all div margins to be 0 except for the div with abc class. to do that just set div element margin to be 0 and div with class abc to be 5px

```css
div {
  margin: 0px;
}

div.abc {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But it's not possible, when you set:

`body{ margin: 0px; }`

In fact you have set that only for body element and that doesn't set for other child elements like DIV or H and other tags ...

I think your code should work properly

Comment: But because of the `DIV` is in the `body`, it select's each tags auto.

Comment: @Eray6421 No, that's just for `<body>` and doesn't effective for child elements, apparently you have different mistake in your code

Answer (score 0):

Setting the margin of the body to zero wouldn't affect affect other margin of the parent elements.

If you want to set margins for parent elements, ensure you do so with figures and unit, the unit is very important, and some of these units are px, rem, em and as well as % (percentage).

And you should also note that "margin" works for margin top, bottom, left, and right.

You can read more on unit here:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Margin: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try adding px to the value 5 in your code above. Values in CSS should always have a unit. It could be px, pt, %, em, rem, etc.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS, you have full control over the margins. There are properties for setting the margin for each side of an element (top, right, bottom, and left).

Add px to 5 and 0, just like the way you will add m or cm to a measurement.